# "Stable equilibrium" of a differential equation for certain $t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = - \sqrt{x}$ where $x(0) = 1$ and $x(t) \geq 0$, defined for $t \geq 0$. The instructor's solution is
$$ 
x(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{(t-2)^2}{4} & \text{ if $t \leq 2$} \\ 
0 & \text{ if $t \geq 2$} 
\end{cases}
$$
I cannot understand this. When I use separation of variables, I solve for $x$, and because $x \geq 0$, I need $t \leq -C$ and I end up finding $C = -2$. If I plug in $t = 2$, I get $0$, so I have $x(0) = 2$ as a "new" initial condition of sorts. I cannot understand why $x(t) = 0$ for all $t \geq 2$. I believe this is called a stable equilibrium, but nothing I've read on the subject confirms this. I should be looking for where $\frac{dx}{dt} = - \sqrt{x} = 0$, which is exactly $x = 0$. I'd then want to construct a sign chart, but I can't do that since I can't take the square root of a negative number. If $x > 0$, then $- \sqrt{x} < 0$ and the rate of change is "negative." I can't relate this back to the values of $t$.

I also think -- unless I am mistaken -- that I've disregarded the $x = 0$ case immediately because I have to divide by $- \sqrt{x}$ to separate variables. I think I then know it's a solution by looking for equilibrium solutions.

I'm very sorry for my ignorance, but could someone please help me to understand the second half of this solution and how one would go about finding it?

Comment: Methods such as *separation of variables* are useful to find (families of) solutions, but they don't always find all solutions. This is one of a standard set of examples of ODEs that do not have unique solutions through certain initial values (specifically for initial value with $x_0 = 0$, which is different from your example). Here's an interactive [Desmos notebook](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rnssxicr5d) I created for teaching this example. You can drag the initial value around and see solution curves dive down to the $t$-axis along a parabola, where they stay.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables gives
$$
-\int x^{-1/2} dx = \int dt
$$
$$
t = -2x^{1/2}+C
$$
Substitution of $t=0,x=1$ gives $C=2$ and the first part of the solution follows.

The first part of the solution $\frac{(t-2)^2}{2}$ only solves the ODE for $t\leq2$, because if $t>2$, then $-\sqrt{x}=\frac{2-t}{2}\neq\frac{dx}{dt}$. Once $x=0$, the differential equation gives $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$, in other words $x$ is constant.

With regards to your question about stability, the range of $x(t)$ is restricted to the positive real numbers because of the statement of the ODE. This means that any perturbation of the stable solution $x=0$ needs to be positive, and these perturbed solutions converge back to the stable solution (in finite time).

Comment: I really appreciate the help and understand what you've written here. If I understand you correctly, I should think of $x(t)$ as a function of time, so $x(2)$ is constant, for every time after $t = 2$, $x(t)$ is also constant at $0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct